# want to get rid of Overwriting in filehandling

Tags: file-handling

My code is perfect but still my cursor is on the beginning of text my and keep overwriting previous input whenever I give new input

```
String username=Cuser.getText();
String password=Cpass.getText();

FileWriter filewriter;
try{
    filewriter=new FileWriter("Record.txt");

    try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(filewriter)) {

      bufferedWriter.write("Username"+" :" + username+"  Password"+" :" + password+"\n");
     //   bufferedWriter.write();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Created Successfully!");
     bufferedWriter.close();
    }
} catch (IOException ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!");
    System.out.println("Error! ");

}
```

Comment: What makes you think that this part of the code is where the cause of the problem lies?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out my error

try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(filewriter) Visible    )

that visible was at end was not in my program which was causing to create new data each timing